# Why ethyl ethanoate and not acetic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In saponification reaction ethyl ethanoate is made to react with NaOH to form sodium acetate as the soap and ethanol as a by-product.
My question is : Why don't we use ethanoic acid instead of ethyl ethanoate to form sodium acetate which is the soap and water as another product?

Comment: You could do so. However, saponification is generally applied on fats (basically long-chain esters) which are found in abundance. Finding an acid such as ethanoic acid in bulk in nature is quite hard.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb Please don’t use comments to answer a question.

Comment: I doubt that sodium acetate will be an effective soap. A methyl group is not a very effective "greasy" tail.

Comment: Sodium acetate is NOT the soap, as Abhirup Adhikary says. It is the result of a saponification rection. But it is not a soap.

Comment: I just gave example using acetic acid. Moreover, https://www.quora.com/Is-CH3COONa-a-soap

Answer (score 2):

*Saponification* refers to a specific class of reaction during which an ester is transformed into its constituent alcohol and an alkaline metal salt of its acid.

While sodium acetate can be produced from acetic (ethanoic) acid and sodium hydroxide, this reaction is known as an *acid-base* or *neutralisation* reaction. It follows a very different mechanism to a saponification.

The name *saponification*, literally *soap making* is historical; this reaction was a major way of making soaps from various biological fats and oils. The sodium salts of long-chain fatty acids (around $\ce{C18}$) are the main ‘soapy’ ingredient of soap. The corresponding acids were not easy to acquire in large amounts but extracting fatss and oils from biomass was a routine task; hence this specific process was used to generate the salts.

Later, the term was applied to ester hydrolysis using alkaline metal hydroxides in general because these follow the same mechanism and only differ in the specific constitution of reactants and products.

Comment: Your answer is quite theoritical but Mr Aniruddha Deb's answer makes it quite clear to me why is it done with ester. But I appreciate your answer

Comment: Except Aniruddha Deb didn’t actually post an answer.